# Form dropdown onchange event not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and I have a form_dropdown, I wrote a javascript function to set the textbox value based on the selected value in the dropdown. here is my code but it is not working:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('allalerts', $alert_list, set_value('allalerts', $alert_list), array('id' => 'allalerts','class' => 'selectpicker', 'onchange' => 'set_alert_name($(this))')); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function set_alert_name(data) {
    document.getElementById ($alertname['alertname']).value = data.value;
}   
</script>
```

Is it the correct way to do that or there is another way? 
I have tried the following jquery code and also did not work:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('allalerts', $alert_list, set_value('allalerts', $alert_list), array('id' => 'allalerts','class' => 'selectpicker')); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#allalerts").change(function () {
        var selectedText2 =  $("#allalerts option:selected").text();
        $('[name="alertname"]').val(selectedText2);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what does console.write(data) output when placed inside the function?

Comment: Are you sure `onchange` is what you're looking for? `onchange` occurs when the selection, the checked state or the contents of an element have changed. In some cases, that only occurs when the element loses focus. `oninput` event occurs when the text content of an element is changed, which might be what you're actually wanting to do.

Comment: @atoms did not get anything..

Comment: @flioxo I tried ochange() and oninput() and did not work.

Comment: Apologies it's console.log(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('allalerts', $alert_list, set_value('allalerts', $alert_list), array('id' => 'allalerts','class' => 'selectpicker', 'onchange'=>'changeAlert($(this));')); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeAlert(obj)
{
    var selectedText = obj.children(':selected').text();
    $('[name="alertname"]').val(selectedText);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do it.

```
$("#allalerts").change(function () {
    var selectedText2 = this.value;
   $('[name="alertname"]').val(selectedText2);
});

// Second Technique.
$(function() {
    $("#allalerts").change(function() {
         var selectedText2 = $('option:selected', this).text();
         $('[name="alertname"]').val(selectedText2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this way but I am not getting the alert message so I think the javascript function is not called when I change in the dropdown. 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#allalerts").change(function() {
var selectedText2 = $('option:selected', this).text();
alert(selectedText2);
$('[name="$alertname['alertname']"]').val(selectedText2);
 });
 });
</script>

Comment: @osamashaki if my suggested answer helps you to then you can accept my answer and also you can give up to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('allalerts', $alert_list, set_value('allalerts', $alert_list), array('id' => 'allalerts', 'class' => 'selectpicker')); ?>

<input type="text" name="alert_name" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#allalerts',function(){
        var temp_name = $("select[name='allalerts'] option:selected").text();
        $("input[name='alert_name']").val(temp_name);
    });
});
</script>
```

A few note, the 'onchange' array in form_dropdown is removed, so the event handler is stated in jQuery.

Notice the `$(documnt).on('change','#allalerts',function(){` it is for the DOM that is dynamically added to web page, otherwise it will not be recognized by jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I trid your code but it did not work. I put alert() inside javascript function but it is not fired when I change dropdown value.